# Login Feature not working in PHP

Tags: php, html, authentication, server

Hi I'm having a little trouble checking this code. It appears to work very fine on my local wamp server but when i went live on a godaddy hosted server, it didn't work. I tried using another server from a different hosting company and it logged me in. I don't know how/where to check for the error.

I also tried changing the php versions on hosting configuration to see if it will actually work, but it didn't.

Can someone please advice

Below is the full code of my login page.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/dbconnect.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "dashboard.html";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "index.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = true;
  mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM lib WHERE username=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Admin Login</title>
  <script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" class="well form-horizontal" method="POST"  id="contact_form">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Admin Login!<!-- Text input-->

</legend>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Username</label>
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Password</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"  type="password">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>      

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is usually a difference between the passwords on your local system and hosted system. Did you try that? Is the connection string the same?

Comment: Also, use `msyqli_real_escape_string` - If your hosting in on PHP 7.x, mysql has been deprecated and you must use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: What was the error appeared? maybe there is something on your dbconnect. your using a native connection which has been deprecated already

Comment: these are the errors i got from my error log 

`[27-Jul-2017 01:11:30 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dbconnect in /home/xxx/public_html/adminpanel/index.php on line 57`
`[27-Jul-2017 01:11:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /home/xxx/public_html/adminpanel/index.php on line 57`

Comment: Are you sure that `Connections/dbconnect.php` is on the server? It looks like you are failing to get a db connection.

Comment: Yes, `Connections/dbconnect.php` is on the server

Comment: Thanks guys, I've resolved it, there was actually a typo in my dbconnect.php file that was why it  wasn't working. I've crosschecked and confirmed everything. working perfectly now. I appreciate your comments

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `Connections/dbconnect.php` is on the server? It looks like you are failing to get a db connection.